# intentar trabajar algoritmo recursivo iterativamente

Tags: java, algoritmos

Hola me gustaría saber si se puede manejar una algoritmo recursivo de forma iterativa, porque yo he intentado poner un botón para correr de forma iterativa sumando las iteraciones pero no puedo porque el algoritmo recursivo lo hace en una sola vez este es el algoritmo de backtracking que estoy trabajando

```
public boolean salir(String[][] lab, int size, int x, int y) {
        boolean salio = false;
        if (y == size - 1) {
            salio = true;
            lab[x][y] = "-";
            return salio;
        } else {
            if (!salio && x - 1 > 0 && lab[x - 1][y].equals(" ")) {
                lab[x - 1][y] = ".";
                salio = salir(lab, size, x - 1, y);//arriba
            }
            if (!salio && y + 1 < size && lab[x][y + 1].equals(" ")) {
                lab[x][y + 1] = ".";
                salio = salir(lab, size, x, y + 1);//derecha
            }
            if (!salio && x + 1 < size && lab[x + 1][y].equals(" ")) {
                lab[x + 1][y] = ".";
                salio = salir(lab, size, x + 1, y);//abajo
            }
            if (!salio && y - 1 > 0
                    && lab[x][y - 1].equals(" ")) {
                lab[x][y - 1] = ".";
                salio = salir(lab, size, x, y - 1);//izquierda
            }
            return salio;
        }
```

Comment: Siempre se puede reescribir de forma iterativa, pero no siempre es sencillo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una forma alternativa para tu algoritmo, hace exactamente lo mismo pero de manera iterativa

```
public static boolean salirIter(String[][] lab, int size, int inX, int inY) {
    int x = inX;
    int y = inY;

    while (true) {
        if (y == size - 1) {
            lab[x][y] = "-";
            break;//Sale del while
        }

        if (x - 1 > 0 && lab[x - 1][y].equals(" ")) {
            //arriba
            lab[x - 1][y] = ".";
            x--;
            continue;
        }
        if (y + 1 < size && lab[x][y + 1].equals(" ")) {
            //derecha
            lab[x][y + 1] = ".";
            y++;
            continue;
        }
        if (x + 1 < size && lab[x + 1][y].equals(" ")) {
            //abajo
            lab[x + 1][y] = ".";
            x++;
            continue;
        }
        if (y - 1 > 0 && lab[x][y - 1].equals(" ")) {
            //izquierda
            lab[x][y - 1] = ".";
            y--;
            continue;
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] lab=init(11);
    String[][] lab2=init(11);
    salir(lab,11,10,0);
    salirIter(lab2,11,10,0);

    print(lab);
    print(lab2);
}

private static void print(String[][] matriz) {
    for (String[] row : matriz) {
        for (String s : row) {
            String p = s.equals(" ") ? "X" : s;
            System.out.print(p + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}

private static String[][] init(final int size) {
    String[][] matriz = new String[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        matriz[i] = new String[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = " ";
        }
    }
    return matriz;
}

public static boolean salir(String[][] lab, int size, int x, int y) {
    boolean salio = false;
    if (y == size - 1) {
        salio = true;
        lab[x][y] = "-";
        return salio;
    } else {
        if (!salio && x - 1 > 0 && lab[x - 1][y].equals(" ")) {
            lab[x - 1][y] = ".";
            salio = salir(lab, size, x - 1, y);//arriba
        }
        if (!salio && y + 1 < size && lab[x][y + 1].equals(" ")) {
            lab[x][y + 1] = ".";
            salio = salir(lab, size, x, y + 1);//derecha
        }
        if (!salio && x + 1 < size && lab[x + 1][y].equals(" ")) {
            lab[x + 1][y] = ".";
            salio = salir(lab, size, x + 1, y);//abajo
        }
        if (!salio && y - 1 > 0
                && lab[x][y - 1].equals(" ")) {
            lab[x][y - 1] = ".";
            salio = salir(lab, size, x, y - 1);//izquierda
        }
        return salio;
    }
}
```

El algoritmo que describes tiene prioridad según va entrando en los **if**

Comment: La idea esta bien, pero no es tan simple. Necesita un stack explicito para realizar el backtracking

Answer (score 0):

Para adaptar tu algoritmo recursivo en su forma iterativa, se necesitan los siguientes cambios minimos:

- Utilizar un stack para almacenar las coordenadas siendo visitadas, el valor inicial para el stack son las coordenadas iniciales.
- Incorporar un `while(true)` a todo el codigo original.

  - Si el stack esta vacio, entonces significa que no hay salida.
  - Obtener el valor actual de `x` e `y` a partir del tope del stack.
  - Ejecutar el algoritmo original de forma normal.
  - En cada llamada recursiva, en lugar de hacerla, agregar al stack los nuevos valores para `x` e `y`, `continue` a la siguiente iteración.
  - Si no se realiza ninguna llamada recursiva, eliminar el tope del stack y continuar a la siguiente iteración.

Con estos cambios el codigo queda:

```
public boolean salirIterativo(String[][] lab, int size, int x, int y) {
    boolean salio = false;

    Deque<Coordenadas> stack = new LinkedList<>();
    stack.push(new Coordenadas(x, y));

    while (true) {
        if(stack.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        Coordenadas coords = stack.peek();
        x = coords.getX();
        y = coords.getY();

        if (y == size - 1) {
            salio = true;
            lab[x][y] = "-";
            return salio;
        } else {
            if (!salio && x - 1 > 0 && lab[x - 1][y].equals(" ")) {
                lab[x - 1][y] = ".";
                //salio = salir(lab, size, x - 1, y);//arriba
                stack.push(new Coordenadas(x - 1, y));
                continue;
            }
            if (!salio && y + 1 < size && lab[x][y + 1].equals(" ")) {
                lab[x][y + 1] = ".";
                //salio = salir(lab, size, x, y + 1);//derecha
                stack.push(new Coordenadas(x, y + 1));
                continue;
            }
            if (!salio && x + 1 < size && lab[x + 1][y].equals(" ")) {
                lab[x + 1][y] = ".";
                //salio = salir(lab, size, x + 1, y);//abajo
                stack.push(new Coordenadas(x + 1, y));
                continue;
            }
            if (!salio && y - 1 > 0
                    && lab[x][y - 1].equals(" ")) {
                lab[x][y - 1] = ".";
                //salio = salir(lab, size, x, y - 1);//izquierda
                stack.push(new Coordenadas(x, y - 1));
                continue;
            }
            //return salio;
            stack.pop();
        }
    }

}
```

Y la clase utilizada para el stack:

```
private static class Coordenadas {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Coordenadas(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

---

Ejemplo ejecucion:

```
* Recursivo *
XXXXXXXXXX
X.X.X...XX
X.X.XXX..X
X.X....X.X
X.X.XXXX.X
X.X.XXXX.X
X.X....X.X
X.X.XX.X.X
X...XX...X
XXXXXXXX.-
* Iterativo con stack explicito *
XXXXXXXXXX
X.X.X...XX
X.X.XXX..X
X.X....X.X
X.X.XXXX.X
X.X.XXXX.X
X.X....X.X
X.X.XX.X.X
X...XX...X
XXXXXXXX.-
```

Codigo para ejecutar ejemplo:

```
public static final String MAZE
        = "XXXXXXXXXX\n"
        + "X X X   XX\n"
        + "X X XXX  X\n"
        + "X X    X X\n"
        + "X X XXXX X\n"
        + "X X XXXX X\n"
        + "X X    X X\n"
        + "X X XX X X\n"
        + "X   XX   X\n"
        + "XXXXXXXX  \n";

public static String[][] getLab() {
    String[] lines = MAZE.split("\n");
    if (lines[0].length() != lines.length) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Laberinto debe ser cuadrado");
    }

    int size = lines[0].length();

    String[][] lab = new String[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            lab[i][j] = String.valueOf(lines[i].charAt(j));
        }
    }
    return lab;
}

private static void print(String[][] lab) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lab.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lab[i].length; ++j) {
            System.out.print(lab[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("* Recursivo *");

    String[][] lab = getLab();

    new BacktrackingMaze().salir(lab, lab.length, 1, 1);

    print(lab);

    System.out.println("* Iterativo con stack explicito *");

    lab = getLab();

    new BacktrackingMaze().salirIterativo(lab, lab.length, 1, 1);

    print(lab);
}
```